# Cancel completion handler (iOS)

Tags: ios, completionhandler

I have a textfield, which fetches data from an API everytime the textField text changes, and updates the table.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
}

func textFieldDidChange() {

    let queryString = self.searchTextField.text

    SearchWSFacade.getSearchResults(queryString: queryString) {
         (error) in

         if (error == nil) {
             self.tableView.reloadData()
         } 
    }
}
```

This works wonderfully, only if the user types slow (allows data to load before typing next character).  If the user types fast, we run into issues, because of multiple calls to reloadData.

This could be solved if I cancelled the completion handler when searching when a previous search is occurring.  How do I do this?  Or is there a better solution?

Comment: You could check if query string is still equal to the textfield's text and and not reload the table if they're different.

Comment: @dan simple, yet effective solution.  Unfortunately I cannot accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: My approach to this is to start a timer when the text changes (say for .5 seconds) and restart the timer when the text changes again. Only when the timer fires do I actually perform the search operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Operations, you can set up dependencies so that one doesn't start until the next one completes. And, unlike blocks, Operations can be cancelled.

Comment: This was actually my next move if I didnt have a simple solution like Dan provided.  Thank you Abizern.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a simple flag in the UIViewController containing the text field - `busyCallingAPI`, perhaps - set it true when you start the API call, set it false in the completion handler, and in `textFieldDidChange` only make the call if  `busyCallingAPI` is false

Comment: I tried using a boolean for this, however, the issue was that longer strings (searching "in progress" vs "in") were being fetched quicker than short ones.